How to read from curl into a string stream in C++?
I'm working with a Web API, reading text data to be processed later. Sometimes the data is rather large, like 90 MB. I'm trying to read it into a std::stringstream, so I can get each line later into a std::string using std::getline().
However, when I use the stringstream with curl, I can't make it work:
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    std::stringstream *stream=(std::stringstream *)userp;
    return realsize;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::stringstream stream;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://date.jsontest.com/"); // simple, small example
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)&stream);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    std::cout << "[" << stream.str() << "]" << std::endl;
    // the loop with getline() would enter here
    return 0;
}

Output:
[]

I adapted the code from here, and noticed they used an istream, but I get a compiler error if I try: basic_istream is protected within this context.
I tried using istream instead of stringstream inside WriteMemoryCallback, have tried removing the (void*) from CURLOPT_WRITEDATA callback, but it always give an empty stream in the end.
I know I can use a string instead, but I think using the getline() may be faster than processing the string myself to spread the lines apart.
I also have tried to read from curl into a string, then pass this string to a stream, and there to the getline, but then I make a copy of the whole string, which is not efficient.
How can I get the data from curl into a stream, and from there via getline() to a string?
EDIT
The more common code for the callback is
static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

And now I see my function is far from it. But I still don't know how to append the new values to the stringstream.

but I get a compiler error if I try: basic_istream is protected within this context. -- Passing a pointer to a std::stringstream to a function that takes a void *, and reinterpreting_cast-ing it inside the function back to a std::stringstream compiles (and works) here.  Maybe you should post code (it doesn't have to be curl-related) to duplicate the error you're claiming.

@PaulMcKenzie Thank you. I added an edit to the post. Still struggling to make it work, though (I don't have much experience with C++, I think it's obvious).

This works fine for me locally. https://godbolt.org/z/Ka4ecYhcx godbolt is sandboxed so it doesn't work there but it compiles fine. I changed the signature of the callback to match the curl docs and avoid another cast. Since your code is not complete with headers and such I did have to invent a little bit. Perhaps that is different than what you have.

@PaulMcKenzie If you can create an example where foo gets two parameters, the first a pointer for the growing stream, and the second a pointer for each small added piece, that would be great.

WriteMemoryCallback() is not writing anything into the stringstream, that is why you are getting empty output.
Try this:
static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    std::stringstream *stream = (std::stringstream *)userp;

    // ADD THIS! 
    stream->write((char*) contents, realsize);

    return realsize;
} 

